# Powerbi: Show only the > 0 values in table

Tags: powerbi

[image]

I want only to see the > 0 values of table Difference, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just to filter the visuals where you don't want your blank and zero values. This is just an example you can also do it like this.

In the Screenshot if you see I have applied a check of greater than 0 so according to this you can apply of less than 0 and it works.

[image]